# Git adding chinese text to xml files when I clone

Tags: git

Everytime I clone/pull/fetch a repo, Chinese text is added between each line of an xml file. I have tried everything I can think of.

The repo comes with it's own gitattributes file. The files are encoded in "utf-16" I've tried to open it with multiple text editors and convert.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't an issue of the tools used to *view* the file, either in the original repo or on your local system or both?  It seems more likely to me that `git` is faithfully cloning the file's content than that it is consistently inserting garbage.  Especially so if it always presents you with the same (you believe erroneous) content.

Comment: Even if it is just a viewer issue that makes you think you get data automagically inserted, however, it might be that there is nevertheless an underlying issue of the file actually being garbled, such as by containing text in a mixture of different encodings.

Comment: Well, I've tried using notepad++ and vscode to open the file. I also tried converting it using notepad++. I've attached a screenshot of what the file is supposed to look like (the way it looks in bitbucket).

Comment: Comparing the two screenshots suggests that it is not a matter of Chinese characters being added, but mainly one of existing text of alternating lines being presented as Chinese (and other) characters.  Toggle your git client's configuration setting for whether to automatically convert line termination sequences.  If the file is really encoded in UTF-16, then naive line-termination conversion could throw the encoded stream out of register and then back in-register on a line-by-line basis, resulting in the text being decoded much as you observe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've set git config --global core.autocrlf to true and false but neither worked. 
Is there another setting I could try?

Comment: I'm pretty confident of my diagnosis, but how about confirming by opening the mangled file in a hex editor.  You should see that for the most part, the bytes alternate between `00` and other values.  In that case, look for places where there are two bytes between `00` bytes instead of one.  I'm betting you'll find such a place at the end of each line, and that the two bytes will in each such case be `0D 0A`.

Comment: As for other settings, it is possible that the repository contains a `.gitattributes` file that erroneously overrides line-termination handling for the affected file.  It should be turned off (`false`) at least for that file.  In that event, you may just need to fix the file (and update the .gitattributes).

Comment: These are random meaningless Chinese characters, so I think it may be an encoding/decoding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot of the garbled file shows that every other line is presented as a sequence of Chinese and other characters.  Comparison with the screenshot of the expected file contents shows that the resulting file does not have the unexpected characters *inserted*; rather, the odd character sequences are presented *instead of* corresponding lines from the original file.

If we accept that the file is encoded in UTF-16 as the XML header says it is, then there is a plausible explanation: you are using Windows, and the effective value of your `git` client's `core.autocrlf` property is `true`, at least for that file.  The resulting automatic line-termination conversions will not do the right thing, because they are not UTF-16 aware.  Automatic line-termination conversion must be *disabled*, at least for the affected file.

When automatic crlf translation is active and the client sees a UTF-16 line terminator in a file it is cloning, whether that's part of a (logical) CR/LF sequence or a bare LF, the LF part will be encoded as `00 0A`.  It takes that as a bare LF because its expected, single-byte-encoded CR/LF would be `0D 0A`. As a result, the client converts such sequences to `00 0D 0A`, three bytes instead of two.  That throws the entire next line one byte out of register, but when the same thing happens at the end of the next line, it will push the following line back into register.  Thus, when viewed in an editor that understands UTF-16, you will see alternating lines of correct and incorrect text, exactly as in your screenshot.

The best way to approach this is probably to make the target file ineligible for line-termination munging altogether, by ensuring that git sees it as binary rather than text (which it is, for git's purposes).  You cannot do this prior to cloning the repository, but you should be able to repair it after.  Do this:

1. Clone the repository.
2. Edit or create a `.gitattributes` file in the same directory as the troublesome XML file, putting a line that unsets the XML's 'text' attribute at the end:

   ```
   name-of-file.xml -text
   ```
3. Force the target file to be re-synced from the origin repository:

   1. `git rm --cached name-of-file.xml`
   2. `git checkout HEAD -- name-of-file.xml`

It is probably worthwhile to look for and remove any assignment there or elsewhere<sup>*</sup> of the `eol` attribute of the XML file, too.  These *shouldn't* be relevant if the file is not considered text, but it's best to minimize the surface area for being affected by bugs.  For similar reasons, I would recommend removing any conflicting specification for the XML file's 'text' attribute.

Don't forget to commit your new / modified `.gitattributes` file(s), at least to your local copy.

---

<sup>*</sup> "Elsewhere" means in another `.gitattributes` file closer to the root of the tree, or in `<repo_root>/.git/info/attributes` if that exists.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. That fixed the issue. I also noticed a line in the .gitattributes files at the root of the repo: "*.xml text eol=crlf" I will get rid of that line. Thanks again